# getAnnotation for Java annotation used on Kotlin method returns null

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin, spring-data-neo4j, spring-annotations

Say, I have the following interface:

```
interface AppRepository : GraphRepository<App> {

    @Query("""MATCH (a:App) RETURN a""")
    fun findAll(): List<App>
}
```

In a test I want to check specifics of the query string and therefore I do

```
open class AppRepositoryTest {

    lateinit @Autowired var appRepository: AppRepository

    @Test
    open fun checkQuery() {
        val productionMethod = appRepository.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("findAll")
        val productionQuery = productionMethod!!.getAnnotation(Query::class.java)

        //demo test
        assertThat(productionQuery!!.value).isNotEmpty() //KotlinNPE
    }
}
```

For a reason I don't comprehend, `productionQuery` is n`null`. I have double checked that the types of the imported `Query` in the test class and the `Query` in the repository are the same.

Thus, why is the `productionQuery` `null` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading annotations on `findAll` from the implementing class (i.e. the class of the `appRepository` instance), not on `findAll` from the interface. To load annotations from `AppRepository` instead:

```
val productionMethod = AppRepository::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("findAll")
val productionQuery = productionMethod!!.getAnnotation(Query::class.java)
```

Comment: dammit :) so embarrasing.